# Why need override layoutSubviews

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, layoutsubviews

In the question "[When does layoutSubviews get called?](http://blog.logichigh.com/2011/03/16/when-does-layoutsubviews-get-called/)" several cases are listed:

1. The parent view is resized
2. The device is rotated
3. Any more?

If there is no requirement to handle, for `UITableView`, we can create a header view for the section header by creating one customized `UIView`. The simplest way is to create the `UIView` by `initWithFrame:` and then there is no need to relayout any more.

Therefore, in my opinion, we do not need override `layoutSubviews` etc. But there are some opinions to insist overriding it.

Reasons to not use it:

1. KISS (keep it simple and stupid )
2. No requirement for relayout
3. Relayout has cost when scrolling

My question here is to get more suggestions for this case. Thanks.

Comment: Keep it simple, stupid. Not simple **and** stupid :)

Answer (score 4):

You don't usually need to override `layoutSubviews`. There are basically only two reasons:

- Your custom `UIView` subclass has subviews that you want to rearrange using manual layout
- Your custom `UIView` subclass needs to know when its size changes for some other reasons, like shrinking a font size or doing some manual drawing

Generally speaking, you don't need to override this method. Most layout is done either by the view controller setting the view's `frame` at appropriate times, or by using auto-layout.

Comment: I still cant figure out how to use the 'manual layout' inside layoutSubviews properly. Do you always use a flag like 'layoutDone' or do you calculate it every time the method is called ? How do you keep constraints from being added multiple times to the view ?

Comment: @petar No, never use a flag and never add constraints there. This method must be indempotent. You just set frames in that method.

Comment: So if I have a view which gets dynamically updated (e.g. I want to add a subview to a particular location, or rearrange currently added subviews, etc) - where should this happen ? Say I initialize a custom view which contains a set of model objects that I want to be displayed when the view is added to a superview. (Initially the view won't know its correct size and the layout of the model objects cant happen properly) - where should this happen you think ? Many thanks

Comment: You should post a new question